# How to tell If Expression to return an empty string in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have an input tag of the date type which value I want to set to `''` if a dictionary doesn't contain an ISODate. If the dictionary does contain an ISODate, then it formats the ISODate into a string so it is displayed correctly:

```
<input type="date" value="{% '' if myDict['date']=='' else myDict['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')%}">
```

But this is the error message:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Probably shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name since `dict()` is a function

Comment: It's just a name for the example, yes it was confusing, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

It should be double curly braces [`{{ your_expression }}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#if-expression)

```
<input type="date" value="{{ '' if dict['date']=='' else dict['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}">
```